# layout autmated testing on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, testing, automated-tests

I'm looking for a way to check if a layout is shown on different devices correctly. I would like to specify e.g. one layout and after tests receive a set of pictures with result how the layout is displayed on a set of devices. It is my dream solution. Can be something similar. My main assumption is see how looks a layout on a lot of screens.

Does someone know a solution (tool) to test in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android Studio** has this feature by default.

To preview the layout on multiple devices simultaneously, select `Preview All Screen Sizes` from the device drop-down.

Hope you can use Android Studio to in order to achieve this :). Please check out below image from **Android Studio**.

[image]